# Toggling boolean value react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why does this not work? If I `console.log` the `todo.completed`, it changes but changes again to the original value.

```js
handleChange(id) {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.completed = !todo.completed
      }
      return todo // Puts todo item in updatedTodos array in the same index
    })
    return {
      todos: updatedTodos
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are mutating the object, which is bad in react and lead to unexpected results

```
handleChange(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
    const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
            // todo.completed = !todo.completed
            //mutating, when mutating react doesn't understand it's a new entity

            //you have to create a new object based on the todo and change the props as you want
            return {
                ...todo,
                completed: !todo.completed
            }
        }
        return todo // Puts todo item in updatedTodos array in the same index
    })
    return {
        todos: updatedTodos
    }
    })
}
```

Comment: @worknovel if you are not familire with spread operator read it here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax when developing with react this will be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

You are mutating the todo object directly which can lead to weird behavior.

Instead of changing the todo in your condition, you will want to return a new todo.

return { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed }

More details here https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array